# error org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.defaultdispatchererrorhandler

Tags: nullpointerexception, struts2

I was trying to convert struts 2.3 to 2.5 after making all the required changes I m getting this exception occurred during processing request nullpointerexception: null and log error: SRVE0293E: [servlet error]-[null] com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.webApperrorreport

Comment: The question is not clear. It has not nessesary details and cannot be reproducible.

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.